# DB::Raw() query to alter the sequence in postgres is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, sequence

I am trying to set the initial value for a primary key in my Postgres database using the following raw query.

```
 // Alter sequence
 DB::raw("alter sequence orders_id_seq restart with 10000");

 //create order
 Order::create([
    'name' => "Hello Order",
 ]);
```

But the order id starts from `1` only instead of `10000`

Then I executed the same SQL query in the database console via Datagrip. Voila, It worked. new database records where appropriately numbered. I wonder why it's not working when I use `DB::raw()`?

I use the same user credentials of postgres for both the laravel application and Datagrip (SQL gui tool).

`Postgres-10`, `Laravel 5.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::raw` alone does not execute the query. 
You should add this in an `DB::update`, something like this:

```
DB::update(DB::raw("alter sequence orders_id_seq restart with 10000"));
```